# Run parallel validation of Uri using WebRequest

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have more Uri's. I need to validate, if they are reachable.

```
public RelayCommand TestConnectionCommand => new RelayCommand(async () =>
    {
        var res1 = await ValidateUriAsync(uri);
        var res2 = await ValidateUriAsync(uri);


    });

private async Task<bool> ValidateUriAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
            var result = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When the program comes to first await it takes some time to validate the uri, after I get the result, I can show the result on the View. Then program goes next and I validate second uri. I'd like to do that parallel, without awaiting. I was thinking about using Begin/EndGetResponse. I need to show the result for each validation on the View. Validation succeeded/failed.

Many thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3):

When using await you stop the execution until the task returns, instead wait for all task to finish:

```
var task1 = ValidateUriAsync(uri);
var task2 = ValidateUriAsync(uri);

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

or to wait until the first fault:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>
{
    ValidateUriAsync(), ValidateUriAsync(uri)
};

while (tasks.Any())
{
    var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        //Faulty
        break;
    }

    tasks.Remove(t);
}
```

Comment: I know about this. But when any of the task throws exception, the result will be Faulted.

Comment: If the result of WhenAll is faulty, then you need to go through your tasks to see which one (or more) of them which caused the fault.

Comment: But using WhenAll I have to wait, when all tasks finish. Then I can loop through all tasks and check if succeeded or failed. What if first validation takes 15sec and second validation 2sec. I will wait 15sec to show the result of validations. I need to show the result immediately.

Comment: @Jup then use `Task.WhenAny` in a loop.

Comment: Updated answer to stop at first fault @Evk

Comment: There is small problem with that: if both tasks fail - you observe result only of the first task. That means second task exception will not be observed and if running on framework version lower than 4.5 - might even crash your application.

Comment: Let's say I have 2 tasks. First one takes 4sec and second one 10sec. First task failed and your break will step out from the cycle.

Comment: I understood it as you didn't care about the remaining tasks if a single task fails.

Comment: @JuP just remove IsFaulted check (together with break). Then it will wait for all tasks to complete but you will be able to perform an action after each one completes\faults (such as update UI).